# Internal server error while deploying with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mysql-python

I'm tying to dockerize a webservice, I configured the following files:

**dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: DB_test
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 manage:app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**sql/init.sql**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test TO 'user'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**sqlalchemy_conf**

```
{
    "HR_API_ID" : "api_id",
    "HR_API_CODE" : "api_code",
    "DB_HOST" : "0.0.0.0",
    "DB_PORT" : "3306",
    "DB_USERNAME" : "user",
    "DB_PASSWORD" : "password",
    "DB_NAME" : "test",
    "DB_CONNECTION" : "mysql"
}
```

After that I run:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

And the log error that appears in the console is the following one when I try to access http://0.0.0.0:8000/:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

And in http://0.0.0.0:8000/:

```
Internal Server Error
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
DB_HOST" : "db"
```

new error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'user'@'172.19.0.3' (using password: YES)") (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

not sure, but running **init.sql** at the beggining should avoid this error

Answer (score 1):

according to https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
your DB_HOST should be `db` which is  your db service name not 0.0.0.0